# Set Share Intent is never used

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to add a share button to my actionbar. The icon displays correctly, however when pressed, nothing happens. It says that my setShareIntent is never used. How do I go about using this?

```
 } @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
    // Return true to display menu
    return true;


}



// Call to update the share intent
private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `Override` method `onOptionsItemSelected` in your activity.

Here is the code you can try.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_item_share) {
        doShare();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void doShare() {

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "I'm Sharing Data");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here is my data");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share myData to.."));
}
```

Refer the Docs :- [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Well, I don't see any use of method `setShareIntent()`. And, In your, it's giving you warning *"setShareIntent is never used"*  because you are not calling that method anywhere in your code.

Comment: It is saying missing return statement

Comment: Check it now. I updated answer. just forget to write that earlier.

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't work. I have it on Github if you want to take a look

Comment: Provide github link. And where exactly you are getting `missing return` error?

Comment: https://github.com/AbanoubG/copticchurch-directory. Perhaps because I am a little new to this. When I press the Share button in the emulator, no share items populate.

Comment: I check your code on github and it seems your old code. Have you tried the code I suggested in answer? And try it on your phone, maybe your emulator doesn't have any app that shares data.

Comment: I tried your code and pushed the apk to my local device however it still doesn't show anything. Am I missing something else? Like in my XML files or something we are overlooking?

Comment: I checked your menu file, and you're using `app:actionProviderClass`. Instead use this `android:actionProviderClass` in your share menu.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you. If I would like to include the Play Store Link to the app, where would that go? I'm guessing I just put the play store link in the EXTRA TEXT field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122972/discussion-between-shaishav-jogani-and-abbanoob).

Answer (score 0):

You should set listener:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
// Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);
item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
       // do something
       return true;
    }
});
// Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
// Return true to display menu
return true;
```

}